# Python code to count the recurrence of a letter in a word

Tags: python, count, recurrence

I need your help to calculate the recurrence of a letter in the word.

```
Input (string): HelloWorld
Output: H1e1l3o2W1r1d1
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Please be aware [so] is not a code-writing service. We can help solving specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details how to help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need a run-length-encoding algorithm on the input.

GeeksforGeeks has a great article on this:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/run-length-encoding-python/

```
# Python code for run length encoding 
from collections import OrderedDict 
def runLengthEncoding(input): 
  
    # Generate ordered dictionary of all lower 
    # case alphabets, its output will be  
    # dict = {'w':0, 'a':0, 'd':0, 'e':0, 'x':0} 
    dict=OrderedDict.fromkeys(input, 0) 
  
    # Now iterate through input string to calculate  
    # frequency of each character, its output will be  
    # dict = {'w':4,'a':3,'d':1,'e':1,'x':6} 
    for ch in input: 
        dict[ch] += 1
  
    # now iterate through dictionary to make  
    # output string from (key,value) pairs 
    output = '' 
    for key,value in dict.items(): 
         output = output + key + str(value) 
    return output 
   
# Driver function 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    input="wwwwaaadexxxxxx"
    print (runLengthEncoding(input))
```

Output:

```
'w4a3d1e1x6'
```

Your Example:

```
input = 'hello world'
print(runLengthEncoding(input))
```

Output:

```
'h1e1l3o2 1w1r1d1'
```

Exactly how you wanted it.

Above code from GeeksforGeeks link.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you can use str.count(). One easy approach is to look at the first letter, count it, then delete all instances of it from the string and repeat. A simple recursive answer might look like:

```
def count(word):
    if len(word) == 0:
        return ""
    return word[0]+str(word.count(word[0]))+count(word[1:].replace(word[0], ""))
```

Answer (score -1):

use `string.count()`.

The syntax is as follows :

```
string.count(substring, [start_index],[end_index])
```

`substring` is the letter you are trying to find, `[start_index]` is the letter at which to start searching (remember, python starts at 0 when using indexes) and `[end_index]` is at which letter to stop searching.

Answer (score -1):

I think this function should do the trick:

```
def countoccurences(word, character):
    occuresin =[]
    for letter in word:
        if letter == character:
            occuresin.append(letter)
        
    print("Letter", character, " occurs in string: ", str(len(occuresin)), " times.")
    return len(occuresin)

countoccurences("1se3sr4g45h7e5q3e", 'e')
```

Comment: @datageek excuse me why did you devote my answer without any explanation?

Comment: This does not answer the question. What it provides is an inferior implementation of ``str.count``, e.g. ``"1se3sr4g45h7e5q3e".count('e')``.

Comment: then you should explain your question better because now it is open for us to interpret to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Note that I am note the question asker. The question clearly states that for the input ``HelloWorld`` the desired output is ``H1e1l3o2W1r1d1``, however.

Comment: I'm sorry. Then I guess I quite litterally misunderstood everything but I believe a correct answer is already posted.